# Django: passing variables from pre_save to post_save signals

Tags: django, django-signals

I use the pre_save and post_save signals to send analytics to Mixpanel. I prefer to keep this separated from my model's save method.

Is there a way to save the old values of an instance when the pre_save signal occurs, and then check the new values against them on post_save?

My code looks like this:

```py
@receiver(pre_save, sender=Activity)
def send_user_profile_analytics(sender, **kwargs):
    activity_completed_old_value = kwargs['instance'].is_completed
    # store this value somewhere?

@receiver(post_save, sender=Activity)
def send_user_profile_analytics(sender, **kwargs):
    if kwargs['instance'].is_completed != activity_completed_old_value:
        # send analytics
```

For me it seems more robust to use post_save to send the analytics than pre_save, but at that point I can't see what has changed in the model instance. I would like to prevent using globals or implementing something in my model's save function.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can store them as instance attributes.

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=Activity)
def send_user_profile_analytics(sender, **kwargs):
    instance = kwargs['instance']
    instance._activity_completed_old_value = instance.is_completed

@receiver(post_save, sender=Activity)
def send_user_profile_analytics(sender, **kwargs):
    instance = kwargs['instance']     
    if instance.is_completed != instance._activity_completed_old_value:
        # send analytics
```

In this way you "send analytics" only if `is_completed` changes during `save` (that means that `save` doesn't just store the value but makes some further elaboration).

If you want to perform an action when a field is changed during instance life-time (that is from its creation till the `save`) you should store the initial value during `post_init` (and not `pre_save`).

Comment: I was already thinking of that, but is that good practice for Django? And why would I make it a protected attribute? Thanks for the post_init hint, that's better indeed.

Comment: @jvannistelrooy: no need for a protected attribute, but it is better you do not use these additional attributes outside those functions, 'cause they are just service fields. I've found this solution somewhere... I'll post the link as soon as I find it

Comment: Could you please also explain why `post_init` is better than `pre_save`? Wouldn't it add extra db queries even when the value is not actually needed?

Comment: I tried this, but `Activity` instance does not have `_activity_completed_old_value` by the time I am in `post_save` when I try to save model